# Translation from English to Russian

Tags: английский, физика

Can someone from Russian-speaking countries (physicist preferably) check the validity of the following translation from English to Russian language:

> Theoretical Predictions of Highly Energetic Particles Energy Loss in Quark-Gluon Plasma
>
> Теоретические прогнозы потерь энергии частиц высоких энергий в кварк-глюонной плазме

Comment: Теоретическое **прогнозирование...** (action, not its result) would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation is correct in general, but some style issues could be here. Probably, you should better ask physicists. I interested in physics only on a popular level, I would translate this as:

> Теоретическое предсказание потерь энергии частиц высоких энергий в кварк-глюонной плазме

Or, "теоретический расчет" instead of "теоретическое предсказание". "Прогноз" is usually applied to wheather forecast.

**UPD.**
Also, you can use "высокоэнергетические частицы" instead of "частиц высоких энергий":

> Теоретическое предсказание потерь энергии высокоэнергетических частиц в кварк-глюонной плазме

BTW, all particles in quark-gluon plasma have high energy. Possibly, this phrase has a tautology.

Comment: "частицы высоких энергий" doesn't sound right to me, "высокоэнергетические частицы" sounds better. Wiki uses both options, so I guess it would be good to ask a physicist.

Comment: I didn't make precise calculations, but imho, both variants are used with approximately equal frequency.

Comment: Neither did I, but it seems that "частицы высоких энергий" is mostly used in articles more closely related to these particles than ones using "высокоэнергетические частицы" which might mean that second term is valid, but considered colloquial. So, I'd better ask a physicist.

Answer (score 0):

> Теоретические прогнозы потери энергии высокоэнергетическими частицами в кварк-глюонной плазме

This clarifies that "particles lose energy" as opposed to "losing particle energy" as in all previous translations, if that is desired. Also avoids repeating `энергии` bare word.